# R:ggplot and for loop ，scale_x_date overwrites one before

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using a simple ggplot function which works fine but `scales_x_date` does not work fine. Why is it so?

Here is my code

```
out <- list(NULL)
datess <- seq(as.Date("1984-01-01"), as.Date("2014-01-01"), by="year")
for(i in 1:5){
  tokyosunt <- sunt[(1+2190*(i-1)):(2190*i), 8]
  dates <- c(datess[(1+6*(i-1)):(6*i)], datess[6*i+1]-1)
  out[[i]] <- ggplot(tokyosunt, aes(x=index(tokyosunt), y=Tokyo)) +
    xlab("") +
    scale_x_date(breaks=dates, labels=date_format("%Y/%m/%d")) +
    ylab("") + 
    geom_line()
}  

png(filename="[3]dailytokyo.png", width = 750, height = 1000, units = "px", pointsize = 12)
grid.arrange(out[[1]],out[[2]],out[[3]],out[[4]],out[[5]],
             ncol=1, nrow=5, left="daily")

dev.off()
```

"sunt" is xts-type data frame, form "1984-01-01" to "2014-12-31".

This code works, but scales of `out[[1]]`, `out[[2]]` and `out[[3]]` were not shown. And in `out[[4]]` only first `scale(2007-12-31)` was shown. Scales of `out[[5]]` are normally shown.

I suppose `scales_x_date` overwrites the one before, scale of `out[[2]]` overwrites  on `out[[1]]`, `out[[3]]` on `out[[2]]`, and so on. What am I missing? And how can I correct it?

Comment: 'scales' doesn't get evaluated until the plot is printed, so each plot will be scaled on `dates` from your last iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to plot 6 year periods of a time-series beneath each other. If you use `facet_wrap` upon a previously computed factor of timespans the code reduces to a few lines:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(xts)

set.seed(123)
sunt <- as.xts(rnorm(10958), seq(as.Date("1984-01-01"), as.Date("2014-01-01")-1,by="days"))
names(sunt) <- "Tokyo"

# Divide the time-series into 6 year periods
sunt$period <- cut(x = time(sunt), breaks = "6 years")

ggplot(sunt, aes(x = index(sunt), y = Tokyo)) + xlab("") + ylab("") + geom_line() +
  scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%Y/%m/%d")) +
  facet_wrap(~period, scales = "free_x", ncol = 1) +
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(), strip.text = element_blank())
```

[image]

If you use `cut` to segment the time-series you benefit from the fact that it accounts for leap years, something that you seem to miss (there are 8 leap years between 1984 and 2014).

Comment: Yeah, this seems closer to what he could have been looking for. Not that familiar with `zoo` myself.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. I don't know well about how to use `facet_wrap`.

Comment: The [Cookbook for R](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Facets_%28ggplot2%29/) section about facets explains and illustrates this very well.

Answer (score 2):

I like trying to figure out what people are up to, but this one is on the tough side. I played with your code and got:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(gridExtra)
library(zoo)

ncol <- 8
nrow <- 5*2190
sunt <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(ncol*nrow),nrow,ncol))

out <- list(NULL)
datess <- seq(as.Date("1984-01-01"), as.Date("2014-01-01"), by="year")
for(i in 1:5){
  tokyosunt <- data.frame(sunt[(1+2190*(i-1)):(2190*i), 8])
  names(tokyosunt) <- "Tokyo"
  tokyosunt$x <- as.Date(index(tokyosunt)*5,origin=as.Date("1984-01-01"))
  dates <- c(datess[(1+6*(i-1)):(6*i)], datess[6*i+1]-1)
  out[[i]] <- ggplot(tokyosunt, aes(x=x, y=Tokyo)) +
    xlab("") +
    scale_x_date(breaks=dates, labels=date_format("%Y/%m/%d")) +
    ylab("") + 
    geom_line() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=-45,hjust=-0.1))
}  

#png(filename="[3]dailytokyo.png", width = 750, height = 1000, units = "px",
                                                               pointsize = 12)
grid.arrange(out[[1]],out[[2]],out[[3]],out[[4]],out[[5]],
             ncol=1, nrow=5, left="daily")

#dev.off()
```

which gives me this. Which has no errors, and may or may not be what your are looking for:

[image]

Comment: shouldn't it be `index(tokyosunt) + 2190*(i-1)` instead of `index(tokyosunt)*5`? you transform the daily series to 5-day interval time-series.

Comment: Thanks but this is not just what I was seeking. I was sorry for my ambiguous question.

Comment: Quite happy with my 2 upvotes and the fact that wici could make it into a more complete answer. He got my upvote :)